# Need help using ThemeRoller

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I'm using [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/)
to dress up a table I'm using to display XML results based on an XSL transformation.  I have everything working from a technical sense (paging, sorting, filtering), but I'm trying to figure out to use a ThemeRoller theme to make it look like they have on their website.

So far, I have added the following file to my project with its reference:

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

and enabled ThemeRoller themes using the following as per the DataTables website:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mainTable').dataTable( {
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "two_button"
    });
});
```

The table gets styled, but it doesn't look right with the header rows being too wide and things being on multiple lines that should be on one line.  Any indication as to what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks very much in advance.

HTML code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <head runat="server">
      <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <link type="text/css" href="css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript">
      </script>
      <script src="Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript">
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                            $('#example').dataTable( {
                                "bJQueryUI": true
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
    </head>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="example" class="display">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <h3>Title</h3>
          </th>
          <th>
            <h3>URL</h3>
          </th>
          <th>
            <h3>Notes</h3>
          </th>
          <th>
            <h3>
            </h3>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="http://www.roperband.com">Jesse\'s Article</a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="http://www.roperband.com">http://www.roperband.com</a>
          </td>
          <td>Some of Jesse\'s notes</td>
          <td>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html></span>

    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Music Magi: Any way you can post a screenshot of what's going wrong?

Comment: Could you put the html table code?

Comment: @Andrew http://imgur.com/BcNtZ

Comment: @Andres see edited post above for HTML code.

Comment: It looks like padding around the header cells are what is causing it to look that way. I would also check out the font size. A quick test-- .ui-widget-header { padding:0px; }

Comment: ok, but could you also put the resulting HTML in the browser?, thanks. if you use Chrome you can inspect the element and take the html.

Comment: @andres - edited in the original post as per your request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I basing DataTable in this [example](http://www.datatables.net/), check the CSS you have for this example and saw this [file](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/media/css/demo_table_jui.css) solves the problem:

CSS:

```
table.display thead th div.DataTables_sort_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

table.display thead th div.DataTables_sort_wrapper span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -8px;
    right: 0;
}
```

[run code](http://jsfiddle.net/vP8cg/)

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've included this file and now the search box and the pagination buttons are where they should be.  However, the header row is still huge and it still looks nothing like the example on their page.. I feel like I'm still missing something

Comment: It looks like everything's working fine now, but the font isn't the same on all components.  I would think this would be part of the whole theme.. is there something I have to add to be sure my table gets this font? Thanks.. it looks like it's only the header and footer that aren't taking the font.. where it says 'Show 10 entries' and 'Showing 1 to 10 of 41 entries'

Comment: that is configured in the file 'http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/media/css/demo_page.css' on line 5. On browsers IE7 +, Safari and Firefox, you have the tools to inspect and analyze each element that has styles applied.
You can do this in 'http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/themes.html' page.

Comment: I needed this plus the following:

.dataTables_length {
    float: left;
}

.dataTables_filter {
    float: right;
}

.fg-toolbar {
    padding: 5px;
}

And then I changed the default input CSS selector from this:

input, textarea

To this:

input:not(.dataTables_filter input), textarea

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is not yet solved. Please try including jquery.ui.-1.x.x.js. I think jquery ui doesn't work without that.

Comment: You can see from the green checkmark next to the other answer that the original poster considers his problem solved.